# 405 Method Not Allowed with Spring

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc, retrofit

I have the following test for an HTTP endpoint:

```
public static final String DATA_PARAMETER = "data";

public static final String ID_PARAMETER = "id";

public static final String VIDEO_SVC_PATH = "/video";

public static final String VIDEO_DATA_PATH = VIDEO_SVC_PATH + "/{id}/data";

@Multipart
@POST(VIDEO_DATA_PATH)
public VideoStatus setVideoData(@Path(ID_PARAMETER) long id, @Part(DATA_PARAMETER) TypedFile videoData);

@Test
public void testAddVideoData() throws Exception {
    Video received = videoSvc.addVideo(video);
    VideoStatus status = videoSvc.setVideoData(received.getId(),
            new TypedFile(received.getContentType(), testVideoData));
    assertEquals(VideoState.READY, status.getState());

    Response response = videoSvc.getData(received.getId());
    assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());

    InputStream videoData = response.getBody().in();
    byte[] originalFile = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(testVideoData));
    byte[] retrievedFile = IOUtils.toByteArray(videoData);
    assertTrue(Arrays.equals(originalFile, retrievedFile));
}
```

I'm trying to implement the requirements defined by this test with the following endpoint defined in Swing:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/video/{id}/data")
public void postVideoData(@PathVariable("id") long videoId,
        @RequestParam("data") MultipartFile videoData) throws IOException {
    if (videoId <= 0 || videoId > videos.size()) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Invalid id: " + videoId);
    }

    Video video = videos.get((int)videoId - 1);
    InputStream in = videoData.getInputStream();
    manager.saveVideoData(video, in);
}
```

The problem is that I get a "405 Method Not Allowed" error. What am I doing wrong so that my  POST method is not being recognized?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the framework, but does it matter that one says postVideoData and the other setVideoData?

Comment: @Douglas No. One is the client-side Java method and the other is the server-side method. The names don't have to be the same as long as the both communicate with the same HTTP interface.

Comment: OK, I suppose that is done with VIDEO_DATA_PATH etc. Are they set correctly?

Comment: @Douglas Added the constant definitions for clarification.

Comment: Yep, all looks good, sorry I couldn't help. I don't quite understand how the return value for videoSvc.setVideoData is generated, but I don't see how that could cause a problem. Only other guess would be to check that it is the POST which fails. Could the videoSvc.getData call be the one that fails instead?

Comment: @powder366 Did you read the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the client interface expects a `VideoStatus` object returned from the server. I declared the method on the server side to return `void`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already fix your problem, but I got the same error, because I am new with Retrofit too :).

The solution for me, was to put an Annotation to specify the response content type, in my case

```
@ResponseBody
```

Another change that I must did, was to change `void` for a custom status.

Hope this helps or at least gives you a light.

Rgds.

Comment: Do you mean `@ResponseBody`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. RetroFit request calls must have either a return type or Callback as last argument.

So in the RetroFitted API:

```
@POST("/path")
public Void saveWhatever(@Body Whatever whatever);
```

Than in the controller it must be :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Void saveWhatever(@RequestBody Whatever whatever) {
    repository.save(whatever);
    return null;
}
```